# is there a way to convert an illustrator extrude & bevel effect to a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I draw a square in Adobe Illustrator and I extruded to create a 3D bar. but now I would like to add dimension lines and so on to the drawing, but of course these don't snap to the 3D drawing but to the original square instead. Is there a way to convert the created 3D bar to a path so I can actually snap to its lines?

[image]

Comment: **Object -> Expand Apperance**

Answer (score 7):

After you hit the okay button on the 'extrude and bevel' window and while the original 2-dimensional paths that you just extruded are still selected you select 'object' >> 'expand appearance' which will create the new 3-dimensional paths for your shape.

Comment: Note that, in newest versions of AI, this is not possible anymore with the "3d extrude and bevel" default effect, you should use 3D and materials > 3d (classic) > Extrude and bevel (classic)

Comment: The Classic 3D did the trick, thanks!